# How to Devanagari script (especially Hindi language) writing in latex, without a roman script (Transliteration) using Latex or PDFLatex compiler?

Tags: pdftex, hindi

Some of the journal's submission system using Latex/PDFLatex compiler which raises issues to multilingual documents. A similar case happened with me while submitting the pre-print on Arxiv, which raise issues to Devanagari script (mainly Hindi). I have found some of the solutions for this, either conversion to intermediate file format before final .tex file or convert the Devanagari script to Roman script.
**Is there any method where we can directly use Devanagari script (For Hindi text) and compile it through Latex/PDFLatex (instead of XeLatex, LuaLatex, etc.)?**

Comment: https://topanswers.xyz/tex-mar-deva might be a good place to ask this

Comment: There is no way to do it as far as I know. In principle maybe it could be done, but nobody has done it. Why not use an intermediate step?

Comment: This is a real limitation of the ArXiV. The best workaround I know is to trick it into accepting a PDF without realizing that it was compiled with LaTeX.